# Echo PHP when MySQLI query is executed

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo

I'm trying to echo my PHP `while` loop inside an `html` echo.

Basically, I want to echo inside another echo. Is that possible?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'config.php';

if (@$_SESSION['username']) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info`";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>All Crew</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name: </th>
                <th>Middle Name: </th>
                <th>Last Name: </th>
                <th>Age: </th>
                <th>Birth Date: </th>
                <th>Birth Place: </th>
                <th>Gender: </th>
                <th>Martial Status: </th>
                <th>Nationality: </th>
                <th>Email Address: </th>
                <th>Address 1: </th>
                <th>Address 2: </th>
                <th>Course: </th>
                <th>School Graduated: </th>
                <th>Remarks: </th>
                <th>Date Added: </th>
                <th>Status: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>".$record['first_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['middle_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['last_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['age']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_date']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_place']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['gender']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['martial_status']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['nationality']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['email_address']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_1']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_2']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['course']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['school_graduated']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['remarks']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['date_added']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['crew_status']."</th>";
        echo "</tr><br>";
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>';
    }    
}
else {
    header('Location: /practice1/index.php');
}

?>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: PHP doesn't work that way. You can run your code all at once (do the actual echoes that you want, rather than using PHP to echo out PHP), or you can save a file containing PHP and then run it later, perhaps with an include. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: im trying to echo all the records in the table. as you can see above, the html is inside an if statement and once it is correct the entire html code will execute. but im having trouble with the "echo inside echo" thing sorry

Comment: Notice that for configuration files you should use `require_once()` rather then `require()` =]

Comment: okay thank you for that advice @BubbleHacker

Comment: Its important also that you notice that PHP is usually inside HTML and not the opposite, so when you build your page try to have that in mind...

Comment: @unknown The question is, why are you doing an "echo inside an echo" in the first place? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: first echo the entire html code if the session started. second echo inside the first echo is the record @EdCottrell

Comment: @unknown Again, why are you doing that? Just echo everything you want to echo. Don't echo out more PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your your code to this:

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>All Crew</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name: </th>
                <th>Middle Name: </th>
                <th>Last Name: </th>
                <th>Age: </th>
                <th>Birth Date: </th>
                <th>Birth Place: </th>
                <th>Gender: </th>
                <th>Martial Status: </th>
                <th>Nationality: </th>
                <th>Email Address: </th>
                <th>Address 1: </th>
                <th>Address 2: </th>
                <th>Course: </th>
                <th>School Graduated: </th>
                <th>Remarks: </th>
                <th>Date Added: </th>
                <th>Status: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>';
            while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>".$record['first_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['middle_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['last_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['age']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_date']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_place']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['gender']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['martial_status']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['nationality']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['email_address']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_1']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_2']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['course']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['school_graduated']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['remarks']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['date_added']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['crew_status']."</th>";
            echo '</tr>';
          }
         echo '</table>

    </body>
    </html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no echo inside echo...

Not:

```
  echo ' aaa echo "bbbb"; ccccc ';
```

But:

```
echo ' aaa ';
echo "bbbb"; 
echo 'ccccc ';
```

So your code will look:

```
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>All Crew</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name: </th>
                <th>Middle Name: </th>
                <th>Last Name: </th>
                <th>Age: </th>
                <th>Birth Date: </th>
                <th>Birth Place: </th>
                <th>Gender: </th>
                <th>Martial Status: </th>
                <th>Nationality: </th>
                <th>Email Address: </th>
                <th>Address 1: </th>
                <th>Address 2: </th>
                <th>Course: </th>
                <th>School Graduated: </th>
                <th>Remarks: </th>
                <th>Date Added: </th>
                <th>Status: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>';
            while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>".$record['first_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['middle_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['last_name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['age']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_date']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['birth_place']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['gender']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['martial_status']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['nationality']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['email_address']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_1']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['address_2']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['course']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['school_graduated']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['remarks']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['date_added']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$record['crew_status']."</th>";
            echo '</tr>';
          }
         echo '</table>

    </body>
    </html>';
```

Comment: thanks @nospor the code worked. but is there an easier way?

Comment: Well... It is easy way. You just need to remember to quit from echo to normal commands - that how people are doing it. You can also learn a little about templates system  like `twig` and general read about MVC.

Comment: thank you for the advice @nospor. im beginner in php

Comment: twig is just like the same with bootstrap?

Comment: No. Twig is template system. Bootstrap is js/css framework.

Comment: We use Twig to generate html code outside php code. Thx to that we can split application logic from view.

Comment: sir @nospor, if you dont mind. can i have your email address if i have problem so that i can ask you?

Comment: We rather should discuss here :) Here more people have chance to give you right answer. And please, do not use 'sir' ;) Just 'nospor'

Comment: you are very good at php. thank you very much for your help. and thanks for the tips @nospor :)

Comment: If you really will want talk to me you can find me here: nospor.pl (I am making English version but for now there is only Polish but menu I think is quite readable ;) ) There is contact (you can use it to send me mail), forum. I prefer not to set email here because of spambots.

Comment: hi my friend @nospor, are you there?

Comment: can i ask you about mysqli_stmt_fetch?

Comment: Do not ask If you can ask. Just ask ;) I will be again  in front of  computer in 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

Or similar to this: (Note; The tr just above the while loop must also be remove as there is already one inside the while loop.

```
<?php
$loop = "";
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    $loop .= "<tr>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['first_name'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['middle_name'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['last_name'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['age'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['birth_date'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['birth_place'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['gender'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['martial_status'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['nationality'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['email_address'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['address_1'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['address_2'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['course'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['school_graduated'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['remarks'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['date_added'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= "<th>" . $record['crew_status'] . "</th>";
    $loop .= '</tr>';
}

$out = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>All Crew</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name: </th>
                <th>Middle Name: </th>
                <th>Last Name: </th>
                <th>Age: </th>
                <th>Birth Date: </th>
                <th>Birth Place: </th>
                <th>Gender: </th>
                <th>Martial Status: </th>
                <th>Nationality: </th>
                <th>Email Address: </th>
                <th>Address 1: </th>
                <th>Address 2: </th>
                <th>Course: </th>
                <th>School Graduated: </th>
                <th>Remarks: </th>
                <th>Date Added: </th>
                <th>Status: </th>
            </tr>';

echo $out . $loop . '</table>
    </body>
    </html>';
```